# Get max value for every client

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to set an sql query to get the row with the most recent value of updated_at for every user this way:

```
select cr.id_client,cr.updated_at,from_unixtime(cr.updated_at)
from clients_records as cr 
join clients_survey_records as csr 
on cr.id=csr.id 
group by id_client
having updated_at = max(updated_at)
```

But it's not working

Comment: Please qualify the column names so it is clear where the columns come from.

Answer (score 0):

use corelates subquery

```
select c1.* from clients_records c1
where c1.updated_at=( select max(updated_at) from clients_records
                   c2 where c1.id_client=c2.id_client
                     )
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need the `MAX()` function:

```
select cr.id_client, max(csr.updated_at), from_unixtime(max(csr.updated_at))
from clients_records  cr join 
     clients_survey_records csr 
     on cr.id = csr.id 
group by id_client;
```

Answer (score 0):

Good morning.

If I understand You, You can get the most recent modified register. Correct? If it's that, try:

```
SELECT cr.id_client, 
    (
        //Some query to concat and group data contained at clients_survey_records that You need
    ) AS last_survey_records
FROM clients_records as cr 
    INNER JOIN clients_survey_records as cs 
WHERE cr.id_client = cs.fk_client_id 
ORDER BY cr.id_client;
```

You can order easily survey records by updated_at.

Some links:
https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-concat-function.php
https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/aggregate-functions-and-grouping/aggregate-functions-and-grouping-group_concat.php
https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-concat_ws-function.php